# Can I make & Export an animated FBX mesh WITHOUT a skeleton / armature?

Tags: animation, export, shape-keys, unreal-engine

I'm trying to model stylistic plants & trees, and i've made some simple animations to move them.
I've used modifiers and shape keys to achieve my desired effect.
Unfortunately, when exporting the FBX into Unreal Engine, the animation does not transfer correctly, even though it appears correct in the Blender timeline.
I have tried exporting as .MDD and importing again, which applies the motions as individual keyframes, but this does not play when importing into Unreal Engine. It seems that Unreal Engine requires a skeleton when displaying an animated mesh.
Does anyone have any advice for exporting an animated mesh with NO skeleton into a game engine?

Answer (score 0):

you cant export animation without skeleton, you can use Mr Mannequins Tools plugin for blender if animation is not correct